# Is P.O.E.M. India's first superhero team?

Tags: comics, history-of, raj-comics

Brahmand Rakshak (ब्रह्माण्ड रक्षक) possibly first appeared in 2002 with the comics of same name.

[image]

And then, there's *Protectors of Earth & Mankind* (P.O.E.M). It has appeared in dozens of different comics and it consists of even more superheroes including the one's who are in Brahmand Rakshak team. But, I am not sure when the team was formed. But, some of its members like [Nagraj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagraj) were created in 80s.

Also, there are other Indian superhero teams in existence. Which Indian superhero team was the first to come in existence?

Comment: Are you looking for an in-universe or out-of-universe answer?

Comment: Also, are you looking for a superhero team created by an Indian comics company, or by a comics company from a foreign country, but set in India? For instance, if Marvel had created a superhero team based out of India, would that count?

Comment: @Thunderforge Out-of-Universe answer (that's why it has `history-of` tag). Superhero team created by an Indian company.